# Angular 7 Deploy in IIS routing issue

Tags: angular, iis

I have a web application develop in Angular 7, the folllowing application runs smoothly on development with node server but when i upload it on the IIS the routes are not working properly

here is the command i use to compile the app

```
ng build --prod --base-href /hrservicesangular/
```

here is my routing code in angular

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // {path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'prf', component: PrfComponent ,  canActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
  { path: 'leaveobt', component: LeaveobtComponent,  canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'approvals', component: ApprovalsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

];
```

i have also installed url rewrite in IIS and added the web.config with the ff code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/hrservicesangular/" />
      <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />-->
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

i have no problem going into

http://localhost/hrservicesangular/login

and after login i can navigate to

http://localhost/hrservicesangular/home

the problem is when i try to redirect in

http://localhost/hrservicesangular/prf or 
http://localhost/hrservicesangular/leaveobt or 
http://localhost/hrservicesangular/approvals

it always go back to

http://localhost/hrservicesangular/home

i cant seem to figure out the issue, can someone enlighten me? thanks.

> Update:

when i try to change the routes in angular to

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'leaveobt', component: LeaveobtComponent,  canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'approvals', component: ApprovalsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'prf', component: PrfComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]   },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo:'leaveobt', pathMatch:'full' },
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

i can now access the

```
http://localhost/hrservicesangular/home
```

and

```
http://localhost/hrservicesangular/leaveobt
```

it seems like its reading the url

```
http://localhost/hrservicesangular/prf
```

into

```
http://localhost/hrservicesangular/
```

then redirects to

```
http://localhost/hrservicesangular/leaveobt
```

i think i am missing something here in the routes, not sure what it is as it automatically defaults to this route

```
{ path: '', redirectTo:'leaveobt', pathMatch:'full' },
```

but the weird point is i can access  this route

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

and everything else redirects to

```
{ path: '', redirectTo:'leaveobt', pathMatch:'full' },
```

> Update with Answer

i have cleared the cache in my browser(Google Chrome) and updated the routes in angular to this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'approvals', component: ApprovalsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'leaveobt', component: LeaveobtComponent,  canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'prf', component: PrfComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]   },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

It seems to be working fine now, i still cant understand what is the connection in angular routes and the cache in browser as if i have not cleared the browsers cache the issue still persists even with the updated code in the routes.

Anyways just for reference as someone might encounter this issue in the future.

Comment: Can you show how you are redirecting?

Comment: i redirect via manual typing in the url or window.location.href

Comment: In angular avoid modifying the window.locaion.href directly it is preferred to use the router itself <a routerLink="/prf">prf</a>

Comment: yes i can use also routerlink but i needed to reload the page as i have issue in caching thats why i have to use window.location.href or just a simple manual url typing

Comment: Ok so navigation through routerlink is working just direct access isn't. If so that is definitely the rewrite rule. Did you try without the first / in rewrite URL ?

Comment: yes as it turn out there was some issues with the caching in browser which i still dont understand why and i have updated my routes in angular, i will update my question with the workaround i did.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a guess as I never needed to do this before.

could be the first /

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="hrservicesangular/" />
```

Routes order are meaningful so ** must be the last one because it means capture all.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'prf', component: PrfComponent ,  canActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
  { path: 'leaveobt', component: LeaveobtComponent,  canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'approvals', component: ApprovalsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full' },
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

Or redirecting to the wrong path leading to capture all -> login and your login is checking if already logged in and redirect to home.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the routes order, i have updated the question